# Simple mailing form with check boxes

Tags: php, forms, email, checkbox, mailto

Venerable masters of all things code,
I am a simple graphic (not even web) designer, struggling to creating a working mailing script.

So far, I managed to do it with basic HTML and a *mailto* function, but it needs to happen server-side, so, I am guessing PHP is my best bet.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<form action="mailto:?subject=Hello" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry1" value="URL1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry2" value="URL2">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry3" value="URL3">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry4" value="URL4">
<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
<label for="email">Email(Required)</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required class="inputfield">
<input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="">
</form>
```

What I am trying to accomplish:

1. An email to be sent from abc@email.com "email" field and a CC to 321@email.com
2. With a message and Values (URL1,URL2...) from checked Boxes (Entry1,Entry2...)
3. If successful, redirect to a thank you page.

Comment: can you post your email sending code (using mail() function maybe ) ?

Comment: you probably need to create another page that processes the form and sends the email.

Comment: For one thing, it's not going to work using `action="mailto:?subject=Hello"`. Haven't you Google'd `"form email php"`? We're here to help with problems you may have with an already running/working script, not to "write a script" all **tailor-made** for you. That's not what SO is about. Try this: https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+email+form&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr

Comment: **>>** https://www.google.ca/search?q=php+email+form+examples&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

 $_POST['email'];
 $_POST['name'];
 @$_POST['Entry1'];
 @$_POST['Entry2'];
 @$_POST['Entry3'];
@$_POST['Entry4'];

$to      =  $_POST['email'];
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = $_POST['name'] . @$_POST['Entry1'] . @$_POST['Entry2'] .   @$_POST['Entry3']    . @$_POST['Entry4'];
$headers = 'From:you@example.com';

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo 'thanks you for your email';
header("where_you_want.php");
}else{
echo 'please try again';
}
```

?>

```
<form action="where_you_want.php" method="POST" enctype="text">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry1" value="URL1">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry2" value="URL2">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry3" value="URL3">
<input type="checkbox" name="Entry4" value="URL4">
<label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" name="name"     placeholder="Your Name">
<label for="email">Email(Required)</label><input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="john_doe@example.com" required class="inputfield">
<input type="submit" name="send" value="">
```

```
this is not the best answer but I test it and sending email with value and you can     change value and play around..I hope its help..
```

Answer (score 0):

`action="mailto:?subject=Hello"`

This is not what you think it is.

`action` specifies the destination URL. `mailto:` links are sent to the client, the server doesn't do anything with them.

Ex:

```
"mailto:mr.smith@matrix.com"
"http://www.domain.com"
```

`mailto` is like `http` here.

---

To send mail using PHP you can the `mail` function or some other implementation. The `action` in your form will have to point to a script on your server.

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. I just showed what I managed to scramble together currently in lieu of my ignorance of PHP. Using the local client and a `mailto`. But, what I want to do, it write something that would handle the email from the server side, sending the same values without a mail client popping up.

Comment: Yes I understood that. You posted no PHP code so I can't comment on that.